# Update Calender Date According to set date

Tags: android

I am developing a feature for warrenty period.There is one TextView and button. When user click on the button, calendar opens. The user selects a date from calendar and this date will be set into that TextView.  Now there is another TextView, one edit text and one spinner. The spinner has two value : month and year. When user enters some numeric value like 13 and select month or year from spinner, second Text View should be updated. 
I am trying to do this but if month added in edit text is more than 12, my concept goes wrong. Please help me.

```
//Month selected
if (selecteditem.equalsIgnoreCase("Month")) {

    String ed = edit_warrenty.getText().toString();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String dateInString = edit_date.getText().toString();
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println("===date===" + date);
        String date1 = formatter.format(date);
        System.out.println("===formateer.formatdate==" + date1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    c.set(month, (month + Integer.parseInt(ed)));
    int newmonth = month + Integer.parseInt(ed);
    if (newmonth <= 12) {
        c.set(newmonth, year, day);
        tvwarrentyday.setText(day + "-" + newmonth + "-" + year);
    } else {
        int in = newmonth - 12;
        int inn = month + in;
        c.set(month, (month + in));
        tvwarrentyday.setText(day + "-" + inn + "-" + year + 1);
    }
//Year selected
}else if (selecteditem.equalsIgnoreCase("Year")) {
    String ed = edit_warrenty.getText().toString();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String dateInString = edit_date.getText().toString();
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println("===date===" + date);
        String date1 = formatter.format(date);
        System.out.println("===formateer.formatdate==" + date1);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    c.set(year, (year + Integer.parseInt(ed)));
    int newyear = year + Integer.parseInt(ed);
    c.set(newyear, year, day);
    tvwarrentyday.setText(day + "-" + month + "-" + newyear);
} else {
    tvwarrentyday.setText("");
}
```

Comment: You might want to check the entered value before setting the month in your calendar(i'm talking about this line : c.set(month, (month + Integer.parseInt(ed))); ).

Comment: ok.i understood. but what can i do when month is more than 12. Then how can i set that on calendar.

Comment: what do you want to happen in that case (month 13)? should it be converted to month 1 of the next year, or should it create an exception and show a warning to the user, or do you want to make sure the user can not even input an invalid value like 13?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to create a period with the data given by the user you can do something like that when month is selected :

```
int newmonth = Integer.parseInt(ed);
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, newmonth);
```

And like that when year is selected :

```
int newyear = Integer.parseInt(ed);
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, newyear);
```

You won't have to check if the value is superior to 12.

Comment: I am trying to add,but month not added successfully.

Comment: Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

     c.setTime(date);
     int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
     int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
     int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     c.add(month, (month + Integer.parseInt(ed)));
     System.out.println("===c.get"+day+"-"+(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)+"-"+year);

Comment: And what is not working ? Wrong value or exception ? btw, why do you always add +1 to your month ?

Comment: Actually , i do not want to add month in current date or month. I need to add  newmonth on a given date(Fixed date).which i already set here in c.setTime(date). i want to extract month from  this date and add new month.

Comment: Okay, then you need to set the date to your calendar, then add newmonth to it like i showed you. If it still not working try setting year,month and dayOfMonth one at a time.